# How to update donation bar when someone makes donation via PayPal?

Tags: php, api, paypal

I use this code snippet for redirecting people to PayPal site when they click on donation button:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method=post target="_top">
    <input type=hidden name=cmd value="_donations">
    <input type=hidden name=business value="mail@example.de">
    <input type=hidden name=lc value="DE">
    <input type=hidden name="currency_code" value="EUR">
    <input type=hidden name=return value="URL-HERE">
    <input type=hidden name="cancel_return" value="URL-HERE">
    <input type=hidden name="item_name" value="MYSITE.de">
    <input type=hidden name=p3 value="1">
    <input type=hidden name=t3 value="M">


    <input type=radio name=amount value="3.00">
    <input type=radio name=amount value="5.00">

    <button type=submit name=submit>DONATE-BTN</button>

</form>
```

Is it possible to make a donation bar that gets updated after someone made donation? And how I accomplish it?

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to [webhook events for payment notifications](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/webhooks/).